Diferencia entre mov y xor para asignación de registros en NASM 2.16.03
Estoy aprendiendo ensamblador, pero aún no me queda claro la diferencia en cuanto asignar valores a los registros con xor y mov.
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, msg ; Supongamos que imprime hola mundo
mov edx, holaLen ; Es la longitud
int 128
mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 1
int 128

xor eax, 4
xor ebx, 1
mov ecx, msg ; Aquí el binario es más corto con mov
xor edx, holaLen
int 128
xor ebx, ebx
xor eax, 1
int 128

Usé "Compiler Explorer" (un compialdor en línea) para verificar el binario generado y resulta que es más corto con xor, pero he visto que en algunos compiladores en línea me marca error y no entiendo porque.
Sé que hay diferentes ASM así me estoy enfocando en los de Linux que al parecer son los más comunes (al menos los más comunes que he encontrado).

xor y mov son dos operaciones totalmente distintas y tu programa solo funciona por casualidad ya que en tu entorno los registros están inicializados a cero.

mov eax, 4 copia el valor 4 en el registro eax
xor eax, 4 realiza la operación lógica eax XOR 4 y almacena el resultado en eax. Si eax es 0, eax acaba almacenando el valor 4. Pero en un programa real eso es prácticamente imposible que suceda.

En general, el único caso en el que puedes utilizar xor para asignar un valor a un registro sin restricciones es en el que inicializas un registro a 0. En ese caso xor REG,REG siempre almacena el valor cero en el registro y es más corto y rápido que el mov.
Si quisieras utilizar xor para las asignaciones tendrías que hacer:
xor eax, eax ; Pone eax a 0
xor eax, 4   ; Almancena 4 

En ese caso podrías sustituir el segundo xor por un or. En otras palabras, cada mov se convierte en dos instrucciones que además te van a modificar los flags.
Espero que te ayude esta respuesta

Gracias, respondió mi duda.
